# MongoDB filtered lookup in C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-.net-driver

this question refers to the example in [How to project specific fields in array on filtered lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45326664/how-to-project-specific-fields-in-array-on-filtered-lookup)
where a filter was applied on the 'joined' table.
Now I want to translate this into a query in C#, but I don't manage to add the filter to the projection. This is as far as I got:

```
db.GetCollection("meta")
.Aggregate()
.Match(new BsonDocument { { "test", "OK" }})
.Lookup("merge","Exp","Exp","kin")
.Project(Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection
         .Include("Exp") 
         .Include("test")
         .Include("kin")
 )
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to work the hard way:

```
db.GetCollection("meta")
.Aggregate()
.Match(new BsonDocument { { "test", "OK" }})
.Lookup("merge","Exp","Exp","kin")
.Project(new BsonDocument {
    { "Exp" , 1},
    { "test" , 1},
    { "kin", new BsonDocument {   
        { "$filter", new BsonDocument { 
            { "input", "$kin"},
            { "as",  , "kin"},
            { "cond",  new BsonDocument {
                { "$eq", new BsonArray { "$$kin.M2", "val"}}}
            }}
        }}
    }})
  .Project(new BsonDocument {
    { "Exp", 1 },
    {"test", 1},
    {"date", 1},
    {"kin.M1",1},
    {"kin.M2",1}, 
    {"kin.T",1 }})
```

but of course it would be nice to use the API of the Mongo Driver.